# Inverted regex : grep with errors allowed

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to create a datatable from some pdf files, which result in data with sometimes some unplanned spaces, e.g.

```
MWE <- c("Gross Domestic Product 2.3",
"blabla 1.5",
"blabla2 6.5", 
"G ross Domestic Product 4.5",
"Another L ine 9.6",
"Gross Domestic Product 6.9",
"G r oss D omes tic Pr o du ct 7.6")
```

I would like to have all the occurences of `Gross Domestic Product`, whether there are spaces or not. But a simple `grep("Gross Domestic Product",MWE)` takes into account spaces

```
grep("Gross Domestic Product",MWE)
[1] 1 6
```

I can do that upstream, for instance by erasing every spaces, e.g.

```
MWE_2 <- gsub("\\s","",MWE)
grep("GrossDomesticProduct",MWE_2)
[1] 1 4 6 7
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to achieve the same result with the `grep` option, which could prove useful for some uses (e.g. not creating a new table)

Comment: `grep("G( *)r( *)o( *)s( *)s +D( *)o( *)m( *)e( *)s( *)t( *)i( *)c +P( *)r( *)o( *)d( *)u( *)c( *)t", MWE)`

Comment: `grep("Gross\\s*Domestic\\s*Product",MWE)`

Comment: @AllanCameron Your suggestion works, but I wondered whether there would be a more concise way to to that...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your suggestion seems to work only if spaces are removed but not added

Comment: Nesting the `gsub()` command within `grep()` is another option if you want to prevent making a new table before matching. `grep("GrossDomesticProduct", gsub("\\s", "", MWE))`

Comment: @stlba That would prevent the actual creation of the table, but it would still have to be created if I understand correctly. I will check which is faster, but I assume not replicating the entire dataset is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your string and use `grep`, as shown below. Idea is to create a `regex` which ignores space if present.

```
MWE <- c("Gross Domestic Product 2.3",
         "blabla 1.5",
         "blabla2 6.5", 
         "G ross Domestic Product 4.5",
         "Another L ine 9.6",
         "Gross Domestic Product 6.9",
         "G r oss D omes tic Pr o du ct 7.6")

gdp_str <- "Gross Domestic Product"
gdp_str <- sub("\\s*", "\\\\s*", gsub('(.{1})', '\\1\\\\s*', gdp_str))
grep(gdp_str, MWE)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work very well. 
Two questions : 
1. You end up inserting `\\s*` before and after every letter, whereas a comment under my question added `( *)`. Which would be better in which case / What are the differences ? 
2. If I understand correctly the way you used the regex, you replace each character with itself followed by a space \\s, which is the end `gsub`. But does the `sub` has any other utility than adding a space at the beginning ?

Comment: Additionnally, it does not seem to be robust to special characters.

Comment: I added space at the start & end to handle the case if the space is present at the start of the i/p string, ` Gros s D o mestic P roduct `